# Change space-separated to comma-separated data

Tags: linux, shell

I'm using `find /usr/local -ls`. It's showing like below:

```
19799045 4 drwxr-xr-x 9 hduser root 4096 Feb 23 11:00 /usr/local
```

I have to make the data comma-separated like below:

```
19799045,4,drwxr-xr-x,9,hduser,root,4096,Feb 23 11:00,/usr/local
```

How to do it?

Comment: Did you search at all? I imagine such questions have been answered multiple times. I'm also not sure this is really on-topic for SO, unless you have a specific programming language you want to do this in.

Comment: duplicate of [Convert ls output into csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573262/convert-ls-output-into-csv)

Comment: but see also [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Why don't you just generate the data in the correct format in the first place? I know, `-printf` is a non-portable non-standard proprietary extension, but so is `-ls`, and you seem to have no problem using that!

Comment: What should happen if the path contains commas? What is the desired output for symlinks?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0):

As a general programming principle, it is much easier to generate data in the format you need than it is to generate it in the wrong format and then translate it.

Since you are already using the non-standard non-portable `-ls` primary anyway, you might just as well use `-printf` instead, if your implementation of `find` has it. Something like this should get you closer to what you need:

```
find /usr/local -printf '%i,%b,%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%Tc,%h/%f'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this lovely awk command:

```
find /usr/local -ls | awk '{s="";for(i=1;i<=7;i++)s=s$i",";s=s$8" "$9" "$10;for(i=11;i<=NF;i++)s=s$i;print s}'
```

If you prefer to put the awk command in a file, or actually read it:

```
{
  s = ""
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    s = s$i","
  s = s $8" "$9" "$10","
  for (i = 11; i <= NF; i++)
    s = s$i" "
  print s
}
```

This will slightly alter the filename at the end if it contains multiple consecutive spaces, or whitespace characters other than plain spaces.  That's just part of the fun when you parse output that wasn't designed to be parsed using tools barely suited to the task.

Answer (score -1):

From another question, you can use the -printf feature

```
find /usr/local -printf "%i,%k,%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%t,%p\n"
```

Then, you can also choose what features you'd like.

Comment: You should note that `-printf` is a non-standard, non-portable extension. Yes, so is `-ls`, and the OP is using that, but there are more `find`s that have `-ls` than there are `find`s that have `-printf`. For example, the one I am using has `-ls` but not `-printf`.

Comment: Don't write "from another question" and copy stuff here; just mark this question as the duplicate that it so obviously is of [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573262/convert-ls-output-into-csv) (specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25914722/2757035)).